# Using wysiwyg editor on frontend templates in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.1.5, wysiwyg

I found so many articles about how to use wysiwyg editor in admin pages, and I was wondering if I could use it in the frontend templates. 
if yes, please tell me how.
I'm using magento 2.1.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In frontend suppose we want wysiwyg-editor on a textarea and textarea having id : `description`

`<textarea id="description" name="textarea_name"></textarea>`

and use below script to load `jquery` and `wysiwyg` `tiny_mce` and assign to `#description`

```
require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup'
    ], function(jQuery){

    var config = '', 
        editor;

    jQuery.extend(config, {
        settings: {
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : 'bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,',
            theme_advanced_buttons2: null,
            theme_advanced_buttons3: null,
            theme_advanced_buttons4: null,
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location: null
        },
        files_browser_window_url: false
    });
    editor = new tinyMceWysiwygSetup(
        'description',
        config
    );
    editor.turnOn();
    jQuery('#description')
        .addClass('wysiwyg-editor')
        .data(
            'wysiwygEditor',
            editor
        );
});
```

As per your's need you can update `wysiwyg` `tiny_mce` configuration. above one just an example.

Comment: It is not working in my case..I tried the same ...

Comment: @ManishGoswami can you share your logic so i can check, by the way what is not working in this code that also mention so i can help you easily.

Comment: it is loading the tiny_mce in my case, but the editor area is not clickable, i am not able to put any data.

Comment: @DeepakKumar click at the top left corner of editor in text area , you will get cursor pointer. once you get pointer you can enter you text or data.

Comment: this is working but have bug for not clickable or click on only left top